# SharePoint 2013 Current Navigation group pages before all other types

Tags: 2013, navigation

When we set up current navigation for showing sub sites and pages, ideally group of pages are displayed below sub sites.

Something like shown in below screen shot.

[image]

Is there any OOB way to show it in reverse i.e. show group of pages before sub sites.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, you want to sort your website and pages Manually. you can do this easily by:

> go to Site Settings -> under Look and Feel click on "Navigation" ->
>   select navigation element to sort manually -> select the element ->
>   click on "MoveUp" or "MoveDown"

Refer Screen: 
[image]